# How to make a change to Magento cart page

Tags: magento

I have a question regarding the cart page in magento. Where do I find the file to edit the copy?

Example of the site I am working on is: http://www.skeletonwatchshop.com/checkout/cart/

When you add an item to your cart, below you get an area where it says "Estimate Shipping and Tax"

I want to change that copy. I can't seem to find the file that has that copy.

Answer (score 0):

The template file responsible for this block on the checkout page is:

```
app/design/frontend/*package*/*theme*/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

If you can't find this template for the theme you're using, replace the package/theme name with the fallback theme, e.g. **base/default**